# Casting generified classes

Tags: java, syntax

I have 2 interfaces: `Data` and `DBObject`.

`DBObject extends Data`. 
They are generics in class `ITree`.

How can I cast `ITree<DBObject>` to `ITree<Data>` avoiding `ClassCastException`?

```
private ITree<DBObject> structure; 

public ITree<Data> getDataStructure() {
    return (ITree<Data>) structure;
}
```

Comment: Try  `public ITree<? extends Data> getDataStructure()`

Comment: Why can't you return it as `ITree<DBObject>` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get a class cast exception here, you get an incompatible types compiler error.

You can do an unchecked cast:

```
return (ITree<Data>) (ITree<?>) structure;
```

but you need to make sure you fully understand why the compiler considers this unsafe (it will emit a warning), and be able to prove that it is *actually* safe; and, importantly, *document* why it is safe.

This is only safe if `ITree<T>` has no invokable methods which accept a parameter involving `T` (unless those methods don't change the state of the instance using the thing involving type `T`).

For example, a `Supplier<T>` can be safely cast to a `Supplier<ParentOfT>`, because it has no methods that accept any parameters.

You could make the return type of the method into a bounded wildcard:

```
public ITree<? extends Data> getDataStructure() {
```

This prevents you from invoking consumer methods on the return value, i.e. it makes those methods non-invokable (sort of).

However, using wildcards in return types is discouraged, because you then can't get rid of that wildcard at the call site.